# Discord Bot's Global Variable Dumped

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, bots

First post; I'm by no means a programmer, first off. I recently built my first Discord bot on node.js, hosted on Heroku. One command sets a global variable (current time) and prints a message to Discord; the other fetches that variable, compares it to current time as of running the command, translates the difference to human-readable format, and prints a message to Discord that includes that duration.

The trouble I'm having is that the second command fails if it's been too long since the first was run, leading me to believe the global variable is getting dumped. My understanding is that worker dynos (which is what index.js is running on) shouldn't sleep unless I've run out of hours, but I've seen no indication that I have, and it happens very early in the month too.

What else would cause this? I just upgraded that Dyno from Eco to Basic; would the dyno being an Eco one cause this, or might something else be afoot?

If an unknown amount of time has elapsed since the first command has run, the second will fall to run in Discord (returns a private message indicating failure). Once the first command has been run, the second will run without issue. Haven't caught anything in the logs one way or the other.

Comment: If you care about a value persisting for an extended period of time, it's better to use an actual database. An application could restart for any number of reasons, for example, an error thrown causing it to crash.

Comment: Heroku's dynos reboot at least once daily, on every deployment, and on scale up/down. You cannot count on a runtime variable persisting. https://www.heroku.com/dynos/lifecycle (You can't rely on the filesystem, either. That gets wiped with every restart, too. This is what databases are for.)

Comment: "My understanding is that worker dynos (which is what index.js is running on) shouldn't sleep unless I've run out of hours"—do you also have a web dyno? If you do, your worker will sleep when your web dyno does.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.